# Do Conservative boys give a d'var Torah on or after their bar Mitzvah?

Tags: social-convention, bar-bas-bat-mitzvah, conservative-judaism

A friend asked me if I would ask you for your help. Do all boys in Conservative Judaism give a *d'var Torah* on their bar Mitzvah, or is that not until after the bar Mitzvah?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, Lisa! I removed the [tag:devorim] tag from your question; that tag is reserved for questions about the weekly Torah portion of Devorim (Deuteronomy 1:1–3:22).

Comment: One way in which this question might be improved (and receive better answers) would be to include why you think a d'var Torah should be given at a particular time. To clarify, by "bar Mitzvah," do you mean the party? The Shabbos? The "bo bayom"?

Comment: There are different minhagim depending on what community or sect you are in concerning the bar mitzvah. Perhaps you should [edit](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/80895/edit) to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

I am unaware of any "formal halacha" that requires this. As a matter of fact, halachically, absolutely no party whatsoever is required for a Bar Mitzvah.

It has been a long-time custom to make some type of Bar Mitzvah party, esp. in U.S. Ideally, this party should be a *Se'udat mitzvah*. To do this, typically, a *siyum* (completion of a Talmud tractate) is made. Sometimes, the Bar Mitzvah makes this siyum, but it could be done by anyone. Regardless, it is common for the Bar Mitvah to make some *D'var Torah* at the celebration. On many occasions, no siyum is made, however, the Bar Mitzvah and, frequently various rabbis, sometimes associate with the family's shul or boy's yeshiva, give Divrei Torah. (The nicest ones I've seen are where the Bar Mitzvah's D'var Torah incorporates some verse or adage into his appreciation of his parents.)

From what I have seen, this is common protocol at Orthodox Bar Mitzvah celebrations. I have not seen this done at Conservative or Reform ones. However, I have seen Bar Mitzvah say a D'var Torah in shul on the Shabbat that they receive their aliyah in Orthodox (in addition to the one they do at the party) as well as Conservative and Reform shuls.

Comment: I've seen quite a few bar mitzvah celebrants make a _siyum_ on one or more _s'darim_ of Mishnah, very few on tractates of Talmud.

Comment: @msh210 I've made an edit. You are correct. Frequently, as my own Bar Mitzvah, there was no siyum, but I gave a D'var Torah.